# UI Checker JavaScript / CSS tool

Tags: javascript, user-interface

I have a task (for instance): create an HTML&CSS according to the given Jpg file.
Basically, what i want, is a simple JavaScript lib (or whatever else it might be) which will allow me to see the transparent gif of the original file (50% opacity) and my actual page, so that i could fit all my classes pixel-to-pixel according to Jpeg.

Does it exist?

Comment: You want a javascript lib that will fit your form inputs over a partially transparent sprite?

Comment: I want my website to be PIXEL_TO_PIXEL exactly like a mock (jpeg).
So, i want to have the Jpeg OVER my website to see where i miss some pixels :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good extension, for Firefox:

http://www.pixelperfectplugin.com/

Comment: GREAT!
thank you SO much! that was EXACTLY what i was looking for. i've seen it some month ago, but never thought i'd need it :) nice catch!

Comment: Very good answer, but the remaining problem are the other browsers, especially IE which may (will) render the page slightly differently.

Comment: Good point. We should point out that just because it's pixel perfect according to this tool, doesn't mean it will be in the 'real world' - but at least it will help you to get closer.